# MySQL database up, but some tables not updating

Tags: mysql, database

I have a mysql db with 10 tables. Each table drives a website where users can look at or submit data to that table.

Now the more popular tables have stopped displaying new data (checking through phpmyadmin). 
The smaller tables are still working fine.

I don't get any errors when submitting. The data just doesn't show up in the database.

It's all on one shared hosting server. How can it be that only certain tables in a database have problems?

Comment: Can you post your database schema? (Export structure from phpMyAdmin

Comment: are you sure you didn't just look over the pagination?

Comment: post the schema, tell us the number of entries per table and tell us what your pages do, preferably post a link.

Comment: I agree with Steven.  A schema dump would be a good place to start.   could be InnoDB vs MyISM,  different table spaces, different grants, etc.

Comment: Are you checking mysql_error() to see if you're getting errors, or just relying on php's error? PHP won't display errors on queries.

Comment: Thanks, guys! I tracked it down to a really stupid bug. *facepalm*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of question comes up from time to time.  Every time I've seen this type of question, it turns out that the app displaying the data is connecting to a different database than the one you're updating through phpMyAdmin.

So my recommendation is to **assume nothing**, and double-check every database connection in both your apps and your phpMyAdmin sessions.

Answer (score 1):

Try to insert data with phpmyadmin in those tables were you have problems.

Answer (score 1):

I have occasionally had trouble with MySQL not updating tables if I have multiple server processes running using the same data files.

I had these problems with MySQL 4.1 where one server was running standalone and the other was running embedded.  MySQL did not generate any error messages on start-up.  I have not tried to reproduce my problems with newer versions of MySQL.